# Bluetooth speaker playback in ubuntu but not windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sound, bluetooth

this is my first time posting question in here, so hope this goes well :p

//the problem happens after i install ubuntu so although it may seems not directly related i think it will be best to post on this thread as well//

I installed ubuntu 14 LTS on an usb, which i then connect my JBL charge 2 to it. However, when i boot into windows 8.1 again, the speaker appears to be paired but theres no playback at all. Note: the speaker still works when i boot into ubuntu again and it works before in windows 8.1.

I went to sound setting - playback and attempted to connect to it, no response from computer. I then try to remove the device from both control panel and the "tile screen" (as in the new interface we get in with windows key(super key)), both show "remove failed".

My next action is to uninstall the bluetooth driver of charge 2 in device manager, which does remove the device in the control panel screen. But then the computer cannot rediscover the device afterwards. The catch is that if i reboot win 8.1, the driver will reinstall itself and it's the exact situation again.

I have also tried going into service.msc and turning bluetooth startup service as automatic and changing the log account, but no luck again. Also, it is always paired to the computer, even if i turn the speaker off.

Any help is appreciated really hope you can help :)

Comment: edit: i can also connect the speaker to my android phone

Comment: Hi, welcome to askubuntu. As you have stated, the speaker works fine in Ubuntu. As it stands, this sounds like a Windows issue because it does not work in Windows. You can ask this question on the other stackexchange site http://superuser.com/ where there are many windows users. You can use your existing stackexchange profile to add an account there.

Comment: @mchid thanks for your response. I was just wondering will there be a slight chance that the registry of the speaker was messed up due to the duo OS, causing it to always act as "remove failed"

Comment: I'm not sure, however, I have posted a possible solution to your issue.  It is possible the bluetooth device is disabled when you shut down ubuntu leaving the device in a disabled state when you boot windows. This solution should resolve this issue if this is what is causing your problem.

Comment: You can safely run TLP on a desktop and there should be no compatibility issues.

Comment: In fact, I tried to go through and disable all of the laptop features in the config file using sed to minimize any unwanted performance issues anyhow. I have installed and used TLP on desktops with no issues and my laptop runs in desktop mode with TLP. You can always completely remove it if you don't like it for some reason with the command: `sudo apt-get purge tlp`

Answer (score 0):

I came across some configurations that may help using an application called TLP. TLP is a power saving application.

There is a slight possibility that the bluetooth device is left in a disabled state when you power down Ubuntu. If this is the case, the device may be disabled when you boot windows.

Now, before you proceed, TLP conflicts with laptop-mode-tools and you will need to uninstall laptop-mode-tools if laptop-mode-tools is currently installed so run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge laptop-mode-tools
```

Also, you will need to add a ppa to install TLP in 14.04 (it is available through the Universe repository in newer versions of ubuntu for future reference).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

Now, install TLP by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Now, edit the configuration by running the following command:

```
sed -i 's/BAT=1/BAT=0/g;s/BAT=2/BAT=0/g;s/BAT=60/BAT=15/g;s/BAT=powersave/BAT=performance/g;s/128 128/254 254/g;s/BAT=min_power/BAT=max_performance/g;s/BAT=low/BAT=high/g;s/BAT=5/BAT=1/g;s/PM_ON_BAT=auto/PM_ON_BAT=on/g;s/PM_ALL=1/PM_ALL=0/g;s/AUTOSUSPEND=1/AUTOSUSPEND=0/g;s/.DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="wwan"/DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="bluetooth wifi"/g' /etc/default/tlp
```

---

*Of particular importance here is the option* **DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="bluetooth wifi"**; *this option is supposed to "prevent other operating systems from missing radios" which may be the problem you are experiencing.*

---

Now, start up TLP using the following command and after doing so, TLP will automatically startup when you boot your computer:

```
sudo service tlp start
```

You may want to change some of the parameters in the configuration file to your own liking.

If you want to adjust the TLP configuration, run the following command to edit the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

When you are done editing the file, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Then, restart TLP to apply any changes you have made:

```
sudo service TLP restart
```

[Click here for more info about TLP.](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/advanced-power-management-tool-tlp-sees.html)

Please post any errors.

Comment: Just want to ask that since you stated it is "laptop mode tools" and I am working on a desktop, will there be compatible issue?

Comment: @ll-g No, there should not be compatibility issues. Only the settings depending on the "power source" such as those that concern battery or AC power are affected. Because you are not using a laptop, these settings will never be used. I use TLP on my HP desktop to manage the processor and USB powersave features and it works just fine. Here is a link which describes this in full detail http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Comment: @ll-g The setting is listed under "Additional functions" as *"Enable or disable integrated wifi, bluetooth or wwan devices upon system startup and shutdown"* Also, if a setting is listed as ON_AC or ON_BAT in your /etc/default/tlp configuration file, only the settings listed as "**ON_AC**" will be applied because you are on a desktop.